# How to store session with value in command.js and call it in beforeEach cypress test?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

Before starting my test I need to set SESSION: 'value' to localhost in order to get my webpage.

If I run the command in file.spec.js everything works fine.

**file.spec.js**

```
 beforeEach(function setCookieSession() {
     cy.setCookie('SESSION','VjAlOMWMtM2JhNy019NjY5LWIwNWYtYTg2ODU44Bm');
})
```

But I want to add this function to command.js to call upon it in every test I need.
Tried this way but doesn't work.

**command.js file**

```
Cypress.Commands.add('setCookieSession', () => {
    cy.setCookie('SESSION', 'VjAlOMWMtM2JhNy019NjY5LWIwNWYtYTg2ODU44Bm')
})
```

**file.spec.js** calling from command.js

```
beforeEach(() => {
    cy.setCookieSession
})
```

Comment: Two things - call with parentheses `cy.setCookieSession()`, and make sure `command.js` is imported in `/cypress/support/index.js`

Comment: You can also move the whole `beforeEach(() => { cy.setCookieSession() })` into `/cypress/support/index.js`, where it will execute at the beginning of every test in the run.